# How do you find the the sum of a list of permutations?

Tags: combinatorics

If you are given the digits 1, 2, 3 and 4 and then are asked to find the number of different 4-digit numbers you can make (repetition is allowed). We can multiply 
$4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 256$ numbers.

Now, what if we are asked to find the sum of all of the numbers made? Is there any rule or efficient strategy to use?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each digit, each number of $1,2,3,4$ have $4\times 4\times 4=64$ possibilities. So, the sum of each digit equals $64\times (1+2+3+4)=640$. So the sum we want equals
$$1\times 640+10\times 640+100\times 640+1000\times 640=\color{red}{711040}.$$

Comment: I don't understand why you did 4 x 4 x 4?

Comment: @anonymous: For example, the number of the numbers of the form $\circ\circ\circ1$ is $4\times 4\times 4$, right?

Comment: Do you mean that the permutations for the first 3 digits is 4 x 4 x 4?

Comment: @anonymous: Yes. So the number of the numbers whose fisrt digit number is $1$ is $64$.

Answer (score 2):

Of the $256$ numbers, $64$ numbers will have each of $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ in the thousands place.  Similarly for the other places.  So you should get $64\cdot(1+2+3+4)\cdot (1000+100+10+1)$

Comment: How did you get 64?

Comment: $\frac14$ of all the $256$ possible numbers.